# How to package a library for cibuildwheel/auditwheel?

Tags: linux, python-packaging, python-wheel

I'm puzzled by an [issue](https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree/issues/270) with Rtree, a Python package that I occasionally contribute to. The package uses [cibuildwheel](https://github.com/pypa/cibuildwheel) to generate binary wheels for PyPI. This package uses ctypes to bind to the C API for [libspatialindex](https://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex).

Here is a high-level description of the process:

1. The wheel building is triggered using GitHub Actions with [`build.yml`](https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree/blob/1.0.1/.github/workflows/build.yml#L127-L174)
2. A local build of libspatialindex is compiled with [`install_libspatialindex.bash`](https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree/blob/1.0.1/ci/install_libspatialindex.bash), and the `*.so*` shared libraries are copied into the Rtree Python package (specifically `rtree/lib`)
3. The wheel building is controlled by [`setup.py`](https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree/blob/1.0.1/setup.py#L26-L76), which copies `rtree/lib` files to the wheel. (Probably [`package-data`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#package-data) would be easier, but that's off-topic). This initial binary wheel is built e.g. `python -m build --wheel` which adds `rtree/lib/libspatialindex.so` and `rtree/lib/libspatialindex_c.so`.
4. [auditwheel](https://github.com/pypa/auditwheel) "repairs" the binary wheel by magically finding the Linux binaries (not sure how this is done), then using `patchelf` to generate a new `Rtree.libs/libspatialindex-91fc2909.so.6.1.1` shared library for the binary wheel.

The end result is a Linux binary wheel with two copies of the shared library (one in `Rtree.libs` and the original in `rtree/lib`). The preferred library is the one created by auditwheel, in `Rtree.libs`.

A workaround could be to remove `rtree/lib`, with the help of [`wheel unpack`](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/wheel_unpack.html) and [`wheel pack`](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/wheel_pack.html).

---

#### Question

How should cibuildwheel/auditwheel be configured to "discover" and use a external library to be used with ctypes? (For instance, the description above is the "bundle binaries in package" approach). This challenge is described by one of the auditwheel [limitations](https://github.com/pypa/auditwheel#limitations) that it cannot statically determine the library dependencies, since the code dynamically loads libraries at runtime using ctypes.

Pointers to modern practices would be much appreciated.